# SPARQL construct/insert query and blank nodes

Tags: mysql, sparql, rdf, graphdb, blank-nodes

I'm trying to create a SPARQL query to construct or insert graphs, following the BIBFRAME 2.0 Model, using a personal database with a lot of datas. I want to get a result like this:

```
Subject a bf:Topic, madsrdf:ComplexSubject ;
rdfs:label "Subject" ;
madsrdf:componentList [ a madsrdf:Topic ;
            madsrdf:authoritativeLabel "FirstSubject" ] ;
```

But I do not know how to do it in SPARQL. I tryed with this query, but I always get a lot of blank nodes (as much as registers with empty "?Subject" fields I have in my database):

```
PREFIX bf: <http://id.loc.gov/ontologies/bibframe/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix madsrdf: <http://www.loc.gov/mads/rdf/v1#>

CONSTRUCT{

    ?subject a bf:Topic, madsrdf:ComplexSubject ;
        rdfs:label ?subject;
        madsrdf:componentList [ a madsrdf:Topic ;
                madsrdf:authoritativeLabel ?firstsubject ];

} where{ service <http://localhost:.......> {
        ?registerRow a <urn:Row> ;
        OPTIONAL{?registerRow <urn:col:Subject> ?subject ;}
        OPTIONAL{?registerRow <urn:col:FirstSubject> ?firstsubject ;}
                     }
}
```

Comment: The first part of the CONSTRUCT query is done for each RDF subgraph that matches the pattern in the WHERE part. So sure, it will be done for each row.

Comment: And in the `OPTIONAL` parts, you use a different variable `?registroRow` instead of `?registerRow`, thus it's not connected, thus, cross-product with a lots of entries.

Comment: Sorry, both of them are `?registerRow`. The problem keeps.

Comment: What do you mean by problem? Can you show some sample data + the corresponding result. This would make the understanding of the problem easier - at least for me :D

Comment: I have a database in http://localhost:....... with a lot of columns (two of them are Subject and FirstSubject) and 1200 rows, however in Subject and FirstSubject there are only 4 rows with values and 1196 empty rows (for this reason they appear in `OPTIONAL`). When i execute my query in SPARQL i get the graphs i want it, relative to the 4 rows with values, but also there a lot of graphs with blank nodes from the empty rows.

Comment: Then why do you use `OPTIONAL` patterns? Have you tried regular patterns instead? Or your backend returns blank nodes as `?subject`'s? Then you have to use `FILTER isBlank(?subject)`.

Comment: @Wences, excuse me, I mean `FILTER (! isBlank(?subject))`.

Comment: Also, `?subject rdfs:label ?subject` is strange.

Comment: I use`OPTIONAL` because there are more lines in the original query. If i run this query without `OPTIONAL` y get the graphs i want it, but when i use `OPTIONAL` not, and i need it. The problem is in `madsrdf:componentList  [ a madsrdf:Topic` but i don't know how solve it.

Comment: @Wences, are you using GraphDB? Are your another problem is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497670/sparql-construct-does-implicit-subject-object-influence-the-result ?

Comment: Yes, i'm using GraphDB 8.1, but my problem isn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

@Wences, AKSW answered you, please read more carefully.
You don't use `?registerRow` in the CONSTRUCT part, that's why it is executed once for each row.